# How get selected text value from the SelectableText on Custom AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar item click?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get selected text from the `AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar` item's click. I have created custom toolbar 'Copy to Notes' where I need selected value in the text format.

Here's how I have implemented it:

```
SelectableText(
'The minimum temperature in Ahmedabad today is likely to hover around 26 degrees Celsius, while the maximum temperature might reach 35 degrees Celsius.',
   style: const TextStyle(
   fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
   fontSize: 16,
   color: Colors.black), contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
       return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar(
           anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
             children: [
                InkWell(
                     onTap: () {
                     //editableTextState.toggleToolbar(true);
                     },
                     child: SizedBox(
                        width: 110,
                        child: Center(child: Text(AppStrings.copyToNotes)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                         onTap: () {},
                         child: SizedBox(
                                width: 50,
                                child: Center(child: Text(AppStrings.copy)),
                              ),
                            )
                          ]);
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use the [onSelectionChanged](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText/SelectableText.html) to save the state of the selection for the buttons to use, just like  [TextEditingController.selection](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/selection.html) does.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // I usualy use the dartpad to run small samples
  if (kIsWeb) BrowserContextMenu.disableContextMenu();

  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  final String initial_text = (
    'Right click (desktop) or long press (mobile) '
    'to see the menu with custom buttons.'
  );
  
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _App();
}

class _App extends State<App> {
  TextSelection? _selection;

  List<Widget> _toolbar_selection_actions() {
    return [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print(_selection!.textInside(
            widget.initial_text,
          ));
        },
        child: const SizedBox(
          child: Center(child: Text('print text')),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () => print(_selection),
        child: const SizedBox(
          child: Center(child: Text('print selection')),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> _toolbar_actions() {
    return [const Text('something')];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SelectableText(
            widget.initial_text,
            onSelectionChanged: (TextSelection selection, _) {
              _selection = (selection.isCollapsed) ? null : selection;
            },
            contextMenuBuilder: (_, EditableTextState state) {
              return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar(
                anchors: state.contextMenuAnchors,
                children: (_selection != null)
                    ? _toolbar_selection_actions()
                    : _toolbar_actions(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or you can use of the functions that the state provides, I would prefer the prior solution if you just want to have access to the selection state; in case you are already using the state for something (like on the sample bellow that removes the selection when printing), you may as well use the selection state from the state.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // I usualy use the dartpad to run small samples
  if (kIsWeb) BrowserContextMenu.disableContextMenu();

  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  final String initial_text = (
    'Right click (desktop) or long press (mobile) '
    'to see the menu with custom buttons.'
  );

  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _App();
}

class _App extends State<App> {
  List<Widget> _toolbar_selection_actions(EditableTextState state) {
    final text = state.textEditingValue;
    return [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print(text.selection.textInside(
            widget.initial_text,
          ));

          // this removes the selection by collapsing the range
          state.userUpdateTextEditingValue(
            text.copyWith(
              selection: text.selection.copyWith(
                extentOffset: text.selection.baseOffset,
              ),
            ),
            SelectionChangedCause.toolbar,
          );

          ContextMenuController.removeAny();
        },
        child: const SizedBox(
          child: Center(child: Text('print text')),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print(text.selection);
          ContextMenuController.removeAny();
        },
        child: const SizedBox(
          child: Center(child: Text('print selection')),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> _toolbar_actions(EditableTextState state) {
    return [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () => ContextMenuController.removeAny(),
        child: const SizedBox(
          child: Center(child: Text('Nothing')),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SelectableText(
            widget.initial_text,
            contextMenuBuilder: (_, EditableTextState state) {
              return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar(
                anchors: state.contextMenuAnchors,
                children: (!state.textEditingValue.selection.isCollapsed) 
                  ? _toolbar_selection_actions(state) 
                  : _toolbar_actions(state),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is printing the selected text but toolbar is not closing on tap of InkWell. Can i have solution for it? Also I was getting "No Material widget found" error when i run your code in the mobile but it was fixed by Wrapping Material Widget in the InkWell.

Comment: To remove the menu just call `ContextMenuController.removeAny()` when it's no longer needed; the "No Material widget found" refers to the `Material` widget that is contained inside a `Scaffold`, my best guess is that you are using a page without a `Scaffold` , `Material` adds quite a few things but you only "need" one at the top of the tree.

Comment: No, Your guess is wrong for "No Material widget found". I have copied same code from yours and run it which is already have `Scaffold`.

Comment: Anyways `ContextMenuController.removeAny()` is worked. Thank you.